# LazyColumn weird behaviour on scroll, when activity's window has transparent color

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-theme, lazycolumn

there is my lazy cloumn:

```
LazyColumn {
        items(20) {
            Text(
                text = "hi$it",
                color = Color.Green,
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().height(50.dp)
            )
        }
}
```

my activity theme has transparent window color.

at first my list looks like this:

[image]

but when I start scrolling, it becomes like this:

[image]

when I change my window color to white, scroll is fine. but I do not know where this weird behavior is coming from.

Comment: Add the activity code to reproduce this issue.

Comment: just an "onCreate" and lazy column inside the app theme.

Comment: How is this set? "my activity theme has transparent window color"